# If I have two mousewheel listeners, how do I ensure that one comes after the other?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousewheel

I'm working on an app that uses Three.js. I've included the [fantastic] OribitalControls.js to help with scene navigation. It has the following code to attach its function to the mouse wheel:

```
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
this.domElement.addEventListener( 'DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox
```

Elsewhere in my app (in a separate file), I have my own `mousewheel` listener. I attach it to the event like this:

```
this.canvas.onmousewheel = this.onMouseWheel.bind(this);
```

The problem is that my `mousewheel` function tells the renderer to render the frame, since something in the scene has changed. Then the `OrbitalControls` `mousewheel` function changes the position of the camera, after the frame has been re-rendered. The next time I change something, I get an annoying 'zoom' because my listener didn't pick up the last little change from the `OrbitalControls` listener.

Is there a way that I can force my `onMouseWheel()` function to always go last?

Edit: Because of the architecture of the app, `OrbitalControls` doesn't know anything about my other `mousewheel` function. Also, my `mousewheel` function can't make any assumptions about the implementation of `OrbitalControls`.

Answer (score 0):

Both js and jquery are a synchronous. Your goal can be acheieved by callback function. Call back is called after the first functions executes completly. Google callback function and you will find lots of examples

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where would the callback function go? Who would call it?

Comment: $(selector).hide(speed,callback);  see here this is an example first hide function will be executed on selector and after hide function is compeltes(spee is parameter of hide) call function is called. Try using this. As i am online from mobile i am not able to parse your code. Please try my example and try to implement